# List one to one foreign key relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

Due to refactorings of our database, I am looking to rename some of the foreign keys in the database. The format of the names of the foreign keys that we want to apply is different depending on the cardinality of the relationship (currently we only have 1-n and 1-1).

I would like to identify all the 1-1 foreign key relationships such that I apply a different naming template to those. And I don't know how to achieve this. So far I can only list all foreign key relationships with this query:

```
SELECT RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME FK_Name
, KP.TABLE_NAME PK_Table
, KF.TABLE_NAME FK_Table
, KP.COLUMN_NAME PK_Column
, KF.COLUMN_NAME FK_Column
, RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME PK_Name
, KP.TABLE_SCHEMA PK_Schema
, RC.MATCH_OPTION MatchOption
, RC.UPDATE_RULE UpdateRule
, RC.DELETE_RULE DeleteRule
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KF ON RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KF.CONSTRAINT_NAME
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KP ON RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = KP.CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

SSMS can obviously extract this data since in the diagram viewer it displays differently the two types of relationships (with a key at both ends of the connecting line).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found it with a little help of a query that sqlmetal uses to generate the mappings:

```
select RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME FK_Name
, KP.TABLE_NAME PK_Table
, KF.TABLE_NAME FK_Table
, KP.COLUMN_NAME PK_Column
, KF.COLUMN_NAME FK_Column
, RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME PK_Name
, KP.TABLE_SCHEMA PK_Schema
, RC.MATCH_OPTION MatchOption
, RC.UPDATE_RULE UpdateRule
, RC.DELETE_RULE DeleteRule
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC
join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KF ON RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KF.CONSTRAINT_NAME
join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KP ON RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = KP.CONSTRAINT_NAME
where KF.TABLE_NAME + '.' + KF.COLUMN_NAME in
(
    select t.name + '.' + c.name
    from sys.indexes as x,
        sys.index_columns as ic,
        sys.columns as c,
        sys.tables as t,
        sys.schemas as s
    where x.object_id = ic.object_id and
          x.index_id = ic.index_id and
          x.object_id = c.object_id and
          ic.column_id = c.column_id and
          c.object_id = t.object_id and
          t.schema_id = s.schema_id and
          ISNULL(OBJECTPROPERTY(t.object_id, 'IsMSShipped'), 0) = 0 and
          x.is_unique = 1 and
         (
            select count(*) 
            from sys.index_columns ic2
            where ic2.object_id = ic.object_id and
                  ic2.index_id = ic.index_id and
                  ISNULL(OBJECTPROPERTY(ic2.object_id, 'IsMSShipped'), 0) = 0
         ) = 1
)
```